# Angular UI Bootstrap Datetimepicker with seconds

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, angular-ui-datepicker

I want to get bootstrap datetimepicker input value in angularjs controller. I am using following custom directive to achieve this . But i am getting the value is undefined. I have added the code related to html and angular code related to the issue.

HTML

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/locale/en-gb.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-resource.js"></script>

    <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date'  id='datetimepickerFrom' datetimepicker  
ng-model="fromDate" >

           <input type='text'  class="form-control" />

           <span class="input-group-addon"> 
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
           </span>
          </div>
         </div>
```

JS

```
'use strict';
var App = angular.module('app',['ngResource']);

App.directive('datetimepicker', function(){
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){

            if(!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

            ngModel.$render = function(){
                element.find('#datetimepickerFrom').val( ngModel.$viewValue || '' );
            };

            element.datetimepicker({ 
                format : 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'

            });

            element.on('dp.change', function(){
                scope.$apply(read);
            });

            read();

            function read() {
                var value = element.find('#datetimepickerFrom').val();
                ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                console.log(ngModel.$setViewValue(value));
            }
        }
    };
});

App.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.fromDate = moment();
}]);
```

Comment: Why are you using the class `date` for the div and not for the input? You should have the `ng-model` and the class `date` within the input element.

Comment: I moved ng-model to input. But still the same result. Please help me solve this sir.

Comment: In this [link](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) they used class date. I followed that.

Comment: @user3844782 Why you are using this datepicker any specific reason?

Comment: @Aravind No not like that. Nothing worked. This came close to undefined.

Comment: what is your requirement

Comment: Check that: (1) Element name is unique, (2) `ng-model` with the name of the $scope variable is unique. Once you have done that, add a print like this: `console.log($scope.fromDate);`. Make sure that you add this print to take place AFTER you select a value.

Comment: @Aravind I want to use the date input value in controller

Comment: @FDavidov Okay. I will do that now and get back to you.

Comment: @user3844782 You can use this https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: @Aravind will it work for getting time also ?

Comment: @user3844782 no. separately you need to include time picker.

Comment: @user3844782 Please check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a package for you to fix your problem which is in the link.
[**LINK**](https://github.com/zhaber/angular-js-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Easy way to achieve it follow these below steps

1. Add this markup.
2. You need to include the following scripts

   - //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js
   - //angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.1.js
   - //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
   - //cdn.rawgit.com/zhaber/datetimepicker/master/datetimepicker.js
   - //cdn.rawgit.com/zhaber/datetimepicker/master/datetimepicker.css
3. Controller will hold the model value in `$scope.date` which contains the **date and time**.

### Update 1

This control does not support Seconds, I would suggest you to go with Angular UI Bootstrap as below
Include the above references expect last two and use the below markup.

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup is-open="popup1.opened"  ng-model="fromDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true"  close-text="Close" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</p>
<div uib-timepicker ng-model="fromTime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="1" minute-step="1"  show-meridian="ismeridian" show-seconds="true"></div>
```

Add this module as a dependency **ui.bootstrap**

Use the below code to combine your value

```
$scope.changed = function () {
var month = $scope.fromDate.getMonth()+1;
var day = $scope.fromDate.getDate();
var year = $scope.fromDate.getFullYear();

var hour = $scope.fromTime.getHours();
if (hour < 10)
 hour = "0"+hour;

var min = $scope.fromTime.getMinutes();
if (min < 10)
 min = "0"+min;

var sec = $scope.fromTime.getSeconds();
if (sec < 10)
 sec = "0"+sec;

 //put it all togeter
var dateTimeString = month+'/'+day+'/'+year+' '+hour+':'+min+':'+sec;

$scope.fromDateTime= dateTimeString;
};
```

Your live ng-model value combined together

```
fromDateTime:{{fromDateTime |date : 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}
```

So by this if the seconds value is changed only you will get the actual Date Time

Comment: this format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss) is not accepted ? Can you help me solve with a simple working custom directive for bootstrap?

Comment: I am not getting any error for this. It logs on console. But it does not work in the above date time format

Comment: do you have teamviewer?